# PHP Regular expression, how to match the first section which includes a [ symbol?

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I've tried to search for this answer all morning, but with no luck,  all i want to do is match [slideshow or [gallery with the included [ bracket..

code as follows.

```
$gallery = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'gallery', true);


if (preg_match("|^/[slideshow", $gallery)) {
    echo "Slideshow was forund";
} else if (preg_match("|^/[nggallery", $gallery)) {
   echo "Gallery was found";
} else {
   echo "No Match found - No Meta Data available"; 
}
```

The regular expression I've used, I though would work like this.
search the start of the string, and using / would escape the [ from being used as part of the regular expression and be part of the search,

regular expressions is just not my thing.... although the more reading i do, it becomes a little more clearer..

Comment: Offtopic(ish) tip: I've found Expresso (http://www.ultrapico.com/Expresso.htm) to be extremely useful for debugging my regexes. Windows only, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (preg_match("/^\[slideshow/", $gallery)) {
    echo "Slideshow was forund";
} else if (preg_match("/^\[nggallery/", $gallery)) {
   echo "Gallery was found";
} else {
   echo "No Match found - No Meta Data available"; 
}
```

Changes made:

The `[` needs to be escaped as its a metachar, the escape char to be used is `\`. Also preg_match expects its first argument(regex) to be delimited between suitable char. So you can do:

```
preg_match("/^\[slideshow/", $gallery)
```

or

```
preg_match("|^\[slideshow|", $gallery)
```

Answer (score 7):

The escape character is `\` not `/`. Furthermore, you need to end the regex with the same delimiter as at the start of the regex. So your code will need to be something like this:

```
preg_match("|^\[slideshow|", $gallery)
```

Comment: Although both answers are correct, this one does a better job of explaining what needed to be changed and why.